# Nested Dlookup VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, dcount, dlookup

I'm trying to display the Vendor Name and a message that a selected PO Number (from a combo box on the form) does not require QA in a message box. The DLookup to get the vendor number from the PO Number works, but I can't seem to nest it to get the Vendor Name string from a separate table. What am I missing in this nested DLookup?

PO Number, Vendor Number, and Vendor Name are all strings.

```
Private Sub VendorName_AfterUpdate()

    Debug.Print Me.VendorName.Value

    If DCount("*", "ZeroAudit", "PONumber='" & Me.PONumber & "' and VendorName='" & Me.VendorName & "'") = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Needs QA"
    Else
        MsgBox "Vendor " & DLookup("Vendor", "Vendors", "VendorNumber = " & (DLookUp("VendorNumber","POHeader","PONumber= [Forms]!QAChecker2!PONumber.Value"))) & " — Does NOT Need QA — DIM and RETAIL CHECK REQUIRED"
    End If
    Me.PONumber.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: Why inline everything? Capture the inner `DLookup` result into a local variable, then use that variable in the outer one - capture the result of the outer result into its own variable, and send *that* to `MsgBox`. You'll have a much easier time debugging if each instruction does only one thing at a time...

Comment: I'm pretty new at VBA, but I'm all for making things simple to debug! Can you show me what that would look like?

Comment: `Dim vendorNumber As String`, then `vendorNumber = DLookup("VendorNumber", ...)`; then `Dim vendor As String`, and `vendor = DLookup("Vendor", "Vendors", "VendorNumber = " & vendorNumber)` -- then you can know which one is failing, and possibly more easily see why, too.

Answer (score 0):

You state:

> PO Number, Vendor Number, and Vendor Name **are all strings**.

As such, you'll need to surround the `DLookup` criteria with single quotes, e.g. as you have here:

```
DCount("*", "ZeroAudit", "PONumber='" & Me.PONumber & "' and VendorName='" & Me.VendorName & "'")
```

You'll also need single quotes here:

```
DLookup("Vendor", "Vendors", "VendorNumber = '" & DLookUp("VendorNumber","POHeader","PONumber= [Forms]!QAChecker2!PONumber.Value") & "'")
                                             ^                                                                                        ^
                                             |                                                                                        |
                    Added single quotes -----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But I would also echo @Mathieu Guindon's comments regarding the use of local variables in lieu of inline `DLookup` expression.

Consider how much easier the following code is to read -

```
Private Sub VendorName_AfterUpdate()
    Dim strVen As String
    Dim strVNo As String

    If DCount("*", "ZeroAudit", "PONumber='" & Me.PONumber & "' and VendorName='" & Me.VendorName & "'") = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Needs QA"
    Else
        strVNo = DLookup("VendorNumber", "POHeader", "PONumber = [Forms]!QAChecker2!PONumber")
        strVen = DLookup("Vendor", "Vendors", "VendorNumber = '" & strVNo & "'")
        MsgBox "Vendor " & strVen & " — Does NOT Need QA — DIM and RETAIL CHECK REQUIRED"
    End If
    Me.PONumber.SetFocus
End Sub
```

You could also surround the `DLookup` expressions with `Nz` expressions to catch null values, and test for empty strings before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

It is little known, but you can also use **SQL** in the filter:

```
DLookup("Vendor", "Vendors", "VendorNumber = (Select VendorNumber From POHeader Where PONumber = [Forms]!QAChecker2!PONumber.Value)")
```